# Removing a string of alphabets from a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript

Suppose that I am storing a value, abcdef in a variable say x in JavaScript and I have to remove abc. The output should hence be def. How to go about this? Please don't go about delete via number of characters to be deleted as what I am interested is deleting a specific string, it can be or 3 or 4 characters. So, I need a more generalized approach to this.

Comment: Are you always replacing a static string? Or does it vary. Is it always the first 3 characters?

Comment: `var result = 'abcdef'.replace(/abc/g,'')`;

Comment: "from the array" --- where the array comes from? In the initial question there was nothing about arrays.

Comment: eep, I confused it. Its not about array, its deleting a particular string from a variable to which another string is assigned. I am so sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can be used for replacing (or removing) a static substring (or pattern) from a string.

By your example:

```
x = x.replace('abc', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(x.substr(3));
```

or

```
console.log(x.replace('abc', ''));
```

Comment: +1 *assuming* they *always* want the first 3 characters removed.

Comment: @Jason McCreary: yep. If not - it would be a lesson to OP about asking questions properly

Comment: Agreed :). I feel a potential meta post resulting from the outcome of this question…